# Thread hangs when constructing WPF UserControl with ASP.Net

Tags: asp.net, wpf

I am using a WPF UserControl to print to XPS which can then be easily converted to PDF (sorry XPS..). It works as a standalone application, but now it's time to see if I can make it work inside Asp.Net

When a user clicks a button in the browser, I expect it to send a request to the server which will then complete the print. At the moment, I can make this work by starting the WPF printer in a separate process with a WCF service, and calling the service from the web application. This way the WPF functions work natively inside a STA process.

I'm quite confident though, that one should be able to hack WPF to work within ASP.NET. Specifically, this means constructing the WPF UserControl while hosted on an IIS IO completion thread (or spawned regular thread).

Currently when I try this, it hangs when constructing the UserControl, likely due to the lack of a dispatcher thread (message pump). I'm sure it could be any WPF Visual or even Window which would suffer here.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used most of the code from http://eprystupa.wordpress.com/2008/07/28/running-wpf-application-with-multiple-ui-threads/

```
private string WrapWPFBasedFunctionCall(string Parameter1)
{
    //Need to host this call to the WPF based function on an STA thread
    string returnedString = "";
    Thread thread = new Thread(() =>
    {
        var p = new My.WPF.PrinterClass();
        returnedString = p.DoPrint(Parameter1);

        //System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.Run(); //Perhaps use this for a longer running Window, but not needed for this issue
    });

    thread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA); //This is essential
    thread.Start();
    thread.Join(); //Wait for the thread to finish

    return returnedString;
}
```

For my own needs, I needed to be able to wait for the returned parameter, and didn't need the Dispatcher after all. It turns out the STA was the key.